# I get an error while decoding data from the API in Flutter

Tags: flutter, http

I am getting Null check operator used on a null value error in this code.
I tried almost every way but it didn't work, I can send you my working call codes if necessary, thank you in advance.

```
  Future callC() async {
    try {
      final response = await http.get(Uri.parse("https://v3.football.api-sports.io/standings?league=204&season=2023"), headers: headers);
      if (response.statusCode == 200) {

        final result = modelSnfLig1FromJson(response.body);
        if (mounted) {
          setState(() {
            Deneme = result;
          });
        }
        return result;
      } else {
        print(response.statusCode);
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print(e.toString());
    }
  }

  Future<void> fetchData() async {
    await callC();

    //await callB();
    //await callA();

    url = Uri.parse(widget.value);
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    fetchData();
  }
```

model class

```
// To parse this JSON data, do
//
//     final modelSnfLig1 = modelSnfLig1FromJson(jsonString);

import 'dart:convert';

ModelSnfLig1 modelSnfLig1FromJson(String str) => ModelSnfLig1.fromJson(json.decode(str));

String modelSnfLig1ToJson(ModelSnfLig1 data) => json.encode(data.toJson());

class ModelSnfLig1 {
  String modelSnfLig1Get;
  Parameters parameters;
  List<dynamic> errors;
  int results;
  Paging paging;
  List<Response> response;

  ModelSnfLig1({
    required this.modelSnfLig1Get,
    required this.parameters,
    required this.errors,
    required this.results,
    required this.paging,
    required this.response,
  });

  factory ModelSnfLig1.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => ModelSnfLig1(
    modelSnfLig1Get: json["get"],
    parameters: Parameters.fromJson(json["parameters"]),
    errors: List<dynamic>.from(json["errors"].map((x) => x)),
    results: json["results"],
    paging: Paging.fromJson(json["paging"]),
    response: List<Response>.from(json["response"].map((x) => Response.fromJson(x))),
  );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    "get": modelSnfLig1Get,
    "parameters": parameters.toJson(),
    "errors": List<dynamic>.from(errors.map((x) => x)),
    "results": results,
    "paging": paging.toJson(),
    "response": List<dynamic>.from(response.map((x) => x.toJson())),
  };
}

class Paging {
  int current;
  int total;

  Paging({
    required this.current,
    required this.total,
  });

  factory Paging.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Paging(
    current: json["current"],
    total: json["total"],
  );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    "current": current,
    "total": total,
  };
}

class Parameters {
  String league;
  String season;

  Parameters({
    required this.league,
    required this.season,
  });

  factory Parameters.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Parameters(
    league: json["league"],
    season: json["season"],
  );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    "league": league,
    "season": season,
  };
}

class Response {
  League league;

  Response({
    required this.league,
  });

  factory Response.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Response(
    league: League.fromJson(json["league"]),
  );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    "league": league.toJson(),
  };
}

class League {
  int id;
  String name;
  String country;
  String logo;
  String flag;
  int season;
  List<List<Standing>> standings;

  League({
    required this.id,
    required this.name,
    required this.country,
    required this.logo,
    required this.flag,
    required this.season,
    required this.standings,
  });

  factory League.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => League(
    id: json["id"],
    name: json["name"],
    country: json["country"],
    logo: json["logo"],
    flag: json["flag"],
    season: json["season"],
    standings: List<List<Standing>>.from(json["standings"].map((x) => List<Standing>.from(x.map((x) => Standing.fromJson(x))))),
  );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    "id": id,
    "name": name,
    "country": country,
    "logo": logo,
    "flag": flag,
    "season": season,
    "standings": List<dynamic>.from(standings.map((x) => List<dynamic>.from(x.map((x) => x.toJson())))),
  };
}

class Standing {
  int rank;
  Team team;
  int points;
  int goalsDiff;
  Group group;
  String form;
  Status status;
  Description? description;
  All all;
  All home;
  All away;
  DateTime update;

  Standing({
    required this.rank,
    required this.team,
    required this.points,
    required this.goalsDiff,
    required this.group,
    required this.form,
    required this.status,
    required this.description,
    required this.all,
    required this.home,
    required this.away,
    required this.update,
  });

  factory Standing.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Standing(
    rank: json["rank"],
    team: Team.fromJson(json["team"]),
    points: json["points"],
    goalsDiff: json["goalsDiff"],
    group: groupValues.map[json["group"]]!,
    form: json["form"],
    status: statusValues.map[json["status"]]!,
    description: descriptionValues.map[json["description"]]!,
    all: All.fromJson(json["all"]),
    home: All.fromJson(json["home"]),
    away: All.fromJson(json["away"]),
    update: DateTime.parse(json["update"]),
  );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    "rank": rank,
    "team": team.toJson(),
    "points": points,
    "goalsDiff": goalsDiff,
    "group": groupValues.reverse[group],
    "form": form,
    "status": statusValues.reverse[status],
    "description": descriptionValues.reverse[description],
    "all": all.toJson(),
    "home": home.toJson(),
    "away": away.toJson(),
    "update": update.toIso8601String(),
  };
}

class All {
  int played;
  int win;
  int draw;
  int lose;
  Goals goals;

  All({
    required this.played,
    required this.win,
    required this.draw,
    required this.lose,
    required this.goals,
  });

  factory All.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => All(
    played: json["played"],
    win: json["win"],
    draw: json["draw"],
    lose: json["lose"],
    goals: Goals.fromJson(json["goals"]),
  );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    "played": played,
    "win": win,
    "draw": draw,
    "lose": lose,
    "goals": goals.toJson(),
  };
}

class Goals {
  int goalsFor;
  int against;

  Goals({
    required this.goalsFor,
    required this.against,
  });

  factory Goals.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Goals(
    goalsFor: json["for"],
    against: json["against"],
  );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    "for": goalsFor,
    "against": against,
  };
}

enum Description {
  PROMOTION,
  PROMOTION_PLAY_OFF,
  RELEGATION
}

final descriptionValues = EnumValues({
  "Promotion": Description.PROMOTION,
  "Promotion Play-off": Description.PROMOTION_PLAY_OFF,
  "Relegation": Description.RELEGATION
});

enum Group {
  THE_1_LIG_REGULAR_SEASON
}

final groupValues = EnumValues({
  "1. Lig: Regular Season": Group.THE_1_LIG_REGULAR_SEASON
});

enum Status {
  DOWN,
  SAME,
  UP
}

final statusValues = EnumValues({
  "down": Status.DOWN,
  "same": Status.SAME,
  "up": Status.UP
});

class Team {
  int id;
  String name;
  String logo;

  Team({
    required this.id,
    required this.name,
    required this.logo,
  });

  factory Team.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Team(
    id: json["id"],
    name: json["name"],
    logo: json["logo"],
  );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    "id": id,
    "name": name,
    "logo": logo,
  };
}

class EnumValues<T> {
  Map<String, T> map;
  late Map<T, String> reverseMap;

  EnumValues(this.map);

  Map<T, String> get reverse {
    reverseMap = map.map((k, v) => MapEntry(v, k));
    return reverseMap;
  }
}
```

I checked the incoming json data and it works when I try it in a different call, but it doesn't work in this code.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `?? "a default value here"` instead of  `!` in **Standing** Model.
in this case should be something like this :

```
group: groupValues.map[json["group"]] ?? Group.Default,
form: json["form"],
status: statusValues.map[json["status"]] ?? Status.Default,
description: descriptionValues.map[json["description"]] ?? Description.Default,
```

I really recommend do that to all the fields so that you avoid the case when a field is *null*.
Also avoid using `!` as much as you can, I think. Hopefully this help.

Answer (score 1):

Make all properties optional like

```
String ? modelSnfLig1Get;
Parameters ? parameters;
```

when you create (by quicktype.io) a model class according to your JSON file try to check null safety and make all properties optional.
I hope this will help you. Thanks